# Get Javascript to returns true if all the individual letters of pattern appear in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to accomplish the following without the use of regex:

> match("abcdef","@C2D!") returns true
>
> match("abcdef","CAfe") returns true
>
> match("abcdef","CG") returns false

This is the code I have so far - jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5UCwW/1/

```
var re = /[^A-Za-z]/g;

function match(string, pattern) {
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    pattern = pattern.toLowerCase().replace(re, "");
    for (var i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if(pattern.indexOf(string[i]) === -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

alert(match("abcdef", "@C2D!"));
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the regex?

Comment: @mrrogers we haven't been taught it on our curricula - so we aren't allowed to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which, as requested, doesn't use a regex:

```
function testAllowedLetters(allowedString, testString) {
    var i, allowedLetters;

    allowedString = allowedString.toLowerCase();
    allowedLetters = {a:0,b:0,c:0,d:0,e:0,f:0,g:0,h:0,i:0,j:0,k:0,l:0,m:0,n:0,o:0,p:0,q:0,r:0,s:0,t:0,u:0,v:0,w:0,x:0,y:0,z:0};
    for (i = 0; i < allowedString.length; i++) {
        allowedLetters[allowedString[i]] = 1;
    }

    testString = testString.toLowerCase();
    for (i = 0; i < testString.length; i++) {
        if (allowedLetters[testString[i]] === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

console.log(testAllowedLetters("abcdef", "@C2D!")); // true
console.log(testAllowedLetters("abcdef", "CG")); // false
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5UCwW/3/)

First we create an `allowedLetters` object from the first argument as a subset of all lowercased letters a through z. Then we iterate through the characters in the second argument and return `false` if we find one which isn't allowed. Otherwise we return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution :

```
function match(allowed, str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    allowed = allowed.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (!isAllowed(str[i], allowed)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function isAllowed(c, allowed) {
    // "char is not a letter OR char is allowed"
    return !isLetter(c) || allowed.indexOf(c) !== -1;
}

function isLetter(c) {
    c = c.charCodeAt(0);
    // "char >= a AND char <= z OR char >= A AND char <= Z"
    return c >= 97 && c <= 122 || c >= 65 && c <= 90;
}
```